# Does the Spotify Android SDK have anything that the Spotify Web-API for Android not have?

Tags: android, spotify

I know that the Android SDK can't get metadata or playlist information from Spotify, and that's why you need to use the Spotify Web-API Wrapper for Android to do these tasks. So if the Web-API does this, what's the point of the Android SDK? Does it provide any methods or functionality that the Web-API wrapper for Android doesn't? If so, can they be used in tandem without conflicts or special configuration?

I'm wondering because I'm trying to develop an app that uses this information and I'm confused as to what the benefits of each are. Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a question for the Spotify team...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spotify Android SDK allows you to actually play full tracks if you integrate it correctly to your Android app. After you complete the authentication flow with an account that has Spotify premium, you can potentially pass in a URI (a unique identifier for a particular song that can be retrieved with the Spotify web API) and play the song through your app without using the Spotify app.

And yes, you can use the wrapper library in tandem with the SDK without conflicts.